# On the Fly created/appended Divs-Not able to get the ID JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating Divs on the Fly. If I try to get the Attribute id of those Divs, I'm not able to get it.

```
$("#displayPanel div").click(function (){ alert($(this).attr("id")); } 

<div id="displayPanel" class="displayPanel"> 
      <div id="heading"> Display Panel </div> <br/> 
      <div id="save" class="saveClass"></div> <br/> 
       <div id="field1" class="my"> </div> 
       <div id="field2" class="my"> </div> 
</div>
```

`Field1` and `Field2` are created and appended to the `DisplayPanel`. And I'm not able to get the id of those divs. But I'm getting the id for those other existing divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [live event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), the `.click()` only works with the elements that are on the page since it got loaded.

```
$("#displayPanel div").live("click", function(){ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you re-bind the event after adding the divs?

You could use the live() method to bind live click events:

```
$("#displayPanel div").live("click", function (){ alert($(this).attr("id")); }
```